# Confused about the use of "to" in a quote

Tags: prepositions

> The former Manchester United star has now hit a record 25 La Liga
>   hat-tricks and has 45 goals this term **to** lead Lionel Messi by three
>   in the race for the Pichichi.

I am confused as to the meaning of "to" in the above paragraph.

Is it like saying *I prefer walking to running*?

Comment: It's like you were chosen "to lead" a parade.

Comment: He collected record goals and hat-tricks *to* (so as to) have the top score, and head the leader-board.

Comment: The _to_ marks the infinitive _lead_; it's shortened from _(in order) to lead_. I.e, it's what's called a Purpose infinitive. If you can substitute _in order to_ for _to_, you've got a purpose infinitive.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think that's why it seems not right, he doesn't have the goals in order to lead Messi. It's just that in having the goals he happens to lead Messi.

Comment: Exactly. In this case, "to lead" was used to mean "**, leading**".